# Can I marry a Muslim man after civil marriage with another Muslim man got split-up (not divorced)?

Tags: nikah, talaq

I got married to a Muslim man in a civil marriage only and got split-up around 3 years ago but still haven't had divorced.

I have now met another Muslim man who I love and we both want to get married under Islam. So can we do this even though I'm not divorced from my civil Muslim husband?

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. You are still married to your (estranged) husband and as such your marriage to this man is unlawful under Islam.

You should first seek a divorce.